# mat-select Maximum call stack size exceeded in select with 800+ options

Tags: angular-material

I am using mat-select to populate an array of objects in the dropdown. there is an option to select and deselect all the values by clicking on ALL. For that, I am emptying the form control assocaiated with it and for selecting all, populating the form control with all the ids. For Small Data , its working fine..For data more than 800, when i am emptying the formcontrol on unselect of al, It throws an error(Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:200)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
 )

component.html

```
 <mat-select [formControl]="courseFormControl" multiple aria-label="Course Name"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedCourseIds">
<mat-option *ngFor="let course of courseList"
           (onSelectionChange)="onCourseSelect($event,courseFormControl)">
            {{course.courseName}}
          </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

component.ts

```
 onCourseSelect(event, form) {
    if(event.isUserInput) {
  let listCourseId =  [];
//data contains the total list
              data.map((val,ind) => {
                if(val.selected === true){
                  listCourseId.push(val.courseId)
                }
              });
          this.selectedCourseIds = listCourseId;

          this.courseFormControl.setValue(listCourseId);
}
```

Error is being thrown , on deselcting all

core.js:15724 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:200)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:130)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:76)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next (Subject.js:47)
    at EventEmitter.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit (core.js:13499)
    at MatOption.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js.MatOption._emitSelectionChangeEvent (core.es5.js:2803)
    at MatOption.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js.MatOption.deselect (core.es5.js:2595)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please fix the spelling error and also format the description with differentiating the description and the error details so it will make your question more readable and it will increase the chances of getting good answers too. (Note: I tried to resolve the spelling and format issues but it was taking time since there are many to correct so I'm requesting you to correct those.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is when we directly assign values to the mat-select component. So instead of pushing value directly into the formControl, use the mat-select apis to deselect the option.

Try the following:

**component.html**

```
<mat-select [formControl]="courseFormControl" multiple aria-label="Course Name" [(ngModel)]="selectedCourseIds" #matSelect>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let course of courseList" (onSelectionChange)="onCourseSelect($event, courseFormControl)">
    {{ course.courseName }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('matSelect') matSelect;

deSelectAll(){
  this.matSelect.options.forEach((x) => {
      x.deselect();
  });
}
```